# Pyomo | ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'ScalarParam' before

Tags: python, optimization, valueerror, pyomo

When the code is executed, the following error appears: `ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'ScalarParam' before the Param has been constructed (there is currently no value to return).`

Hello everyone, I'm trying to optimize a huge model, but here is a part of it capable of creating the understanding of my question:

```
model = ConcreteModel()


model.days = Set(initialize=RangeSet(31))

T = model.days

model.Y = Param(initialize=1) 

model.L= Param(initialize=330)  

model.LL= Param(initialize=3300) 

model.LU= Param(initialize=3300) 

model.U=  Param(initialize=250) 

model.X0=  Param(initialize=0) 

model.M= Var(T,bounds=(0, None), initialize = 10) 

model.X= Var(T,bounds=(0, None), initialize = 10) 

def obj_rule(model):
  return sum( model.X[i] for i in model.days )


model.funcobj = Objective( rule =obj_rule , sense=maximize)

def C1A_rule(model,t):
  return model.Y*model.L<= model.M[t]

def C1B_rule(model,t):
  return model.M[t] <= model.Y*model.U

model.C1A = Constraint(model.days, rule= C1A_rule)
model.C1B = Constraint(model.days, rule= C1B_rule)


def C14_rule(model,i): # constraints do balanço de massa para o setor b1
  if i == T[1]:  #Pyomo Sets are 1-indexed
    return (model.X[i] == model.M[i] + model.X0)
  if i != T[1]:   
    return (model.X[i] == model.M[i] + model.X[i-1]  )

model.C14 = Constraint( model.days, rule = C14_rule)


def C15A_rule(model,t):
  return model.LL<=   model.M[t] / 1.15741e-5
def C15B_rule(model,t):
  return  model.M[t] / 1.15741e-5   <=  model.LU


model.C15A = Constraint( model.days, rule= C15A_rule)
model.C15B = Constraint( model.days, rule= C15B_rule)




SolverFactory('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol').solve(model).write()
```

In this case, what should I do to avoid this error and get a normal completion status? My thanks!

Comment: If I try to run the code above, I get another error: `'ConcreteModel' object has no attribute 'X'` which is due to the fact that there is no `model.X` variable defined, as it appears in the `obj_rule`. Can you fix that?

Comment: Firstly, if shared code is not partial, model.X definition is absent. After than you will see the solution. Also you can ask this type questions to operations research https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I added X to the vars. This is just a partial code, it is not the entire code, but I think it is understandable of what is happening, the error is  "ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'ScalarParam' before the Param has been constructed (there is currently no value to return).". Do someone know what is happening? And how to fix that?

Comment: It is customary to include "everything needed" in the example code to make it reproduce the issue you are having.  That said, when I add the necessary `pyomo` import to your code, it executes fine with no errors.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I found the error, I just forgot to add a parameter to the model through model.parameter, thanks for all your good will!